# Explanation of iterative algorithm to print power set

Tags: algorithm, set

I found this iterative algorithm that prints the [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) for a given set:

```
void PrintSubsets() 
{ 
   int source[3] = {1,2,3}; 
   int currentSubset = 7; 
   int tmp; 
   while(currentSubset) 
   { 
      printf("("); 
      tmp = currentSubset;

      for(int i = 0; i<3; i++) 
      { 
         if (tmp & 1) 
         printf("%d ", source[i]); 
         tmp >>= 1; 
      } 
      printf(")\n"); 
      currentSubset--; 
   } 
}
```

However, I am not sure why it works. Is it similar to a solution where you use a set of n bits, and on each step, add 1 with carry, using the reuslting pattern of zeros and ones to determine which elements belong?

Comment: Yes, it's just like the case you describe using addition, except this one uses subtraction. Note that this implementation fails to output the empty set.

Comment: @GregHewgill Got it now. Feel free to just post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List all integers in the binary base, and light should shine:

```
 {abc}
7 xxx
6 xx-
5 x-x
4 x--
3 -xx
2 -x-
1 --x
0 --- (omitted)
```

The order to enumerate the integers does not matter provided you list them all. Incrementing or decrementing are the most natural ways.

Comment: Little challenge: list the partitions in Gray order, i.e. a single bit changes every time: 111, 110, 100, 101, 001, 011, 010, 000. Do this sequentially.